# Implement method chaining in a class in Python

Tags: python, fluent

I was going through the documentation of using Fluent interfaces in Python and came across this package : https://pypi.org/project/fluentpy/.

I created a rather contrived example to test this like the below Persons class :

```
class Persons:
    def __init__(self, names):
        self.names = names
        
    def get_lengths(self):
        return [len(name) for name in self.names]
    
    def get_name_length_map(self, lengths):
        return {
            name: length
            for name, length in zip(self.names, lengths)
        }
```

As we can see that the methods `get_lengths` and `get_name_length_map` can be chained .

Below is a simple example of how we use this class in the simple case(without using fluentpy):

```
p = Persons(["Subhayan", "Ralf", "Thomas", "Leo"])

print(p.get_lengths())

print(p.get_name_length_map(p.get_lengths()))
```

Can someone please point me to a way in which i can do method chaining here using fluentpy ? Is there some change to the class that i have to do to make it work ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do, nor what you are struggling with. ``fluentpy`` is used by just wrapping an arbitrary object, it is not specific to "your" code at all. FWIW, it seems like ``get_name_length_map`` should *not* take a ``lengths`` parameter, but always call ``self.get_lengths`` (or just compute the ``len`` of each name!) – making chaining obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Return `self` after every chainable method. However, I don't think any of your methods are worthy candidates because they actually return a value that may be used somewhere (a user may want to read this value, but instead, gets an object instead of a number, confusing). `Chainable methods` are used when the function doesn't return arbitrary values other than `null|undefined|None`; for example, if you had a function `popItem`, it could be chainable, but only if you did not return that `popped` value.